# Jquery - Filter li with selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery to filter a list based on a dropdown from a select box. I am using a preassigned data-attribute to filter each list. If the list item has data-attribute equivalent to the value of the selected option then don't do anything, otherwise filter.

HTML:

```
<select id = 'mankList'>
<option value='ALL' selected>Filter By Item</option>
<option data-book1 =undefined data-book2=undefined data-book3='Vegetables' data-book4='Food' data-book5=undefined> Onions </option>
<option data-book1 ='Fruit' data-book2=undefined data-book3=undefined data-book4='Food' data-book5=undefined> Grapes </option>
<option data-book1 ='Fruit' data-book2=undefined data-book3=undefined data-book4='Food' data-book5=undefined> Oranges </option>
<option data-book1 =undefined data-book2='Candy' data-book3=undefined data-book4='Food' data-book5=undefined>Jolly Rancher </option>
<option data-book1 =undefined data-book2=undefined data-book3=undefined data-book4=undefined data-book5='NOA'> Chair </option></select>

<ul><li>Fruit</li>
    <li>Candy</li>
    <li>Food</li>
    <li>Vegetables</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('change', '#mankList', function() {


    var val1 = $('#mankList option:selected').val(),
        val2 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book1'),
        val3 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book2'),
        val4 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book3'),
        val5 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book4'),
        val6 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book5'),
        val7 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book6'),
        val8 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book7'),
        val9 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book8'),
        val10 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book9'),
        val11 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book10'),
        val12 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book11'),
        val13 = $('#mankList option:selected').data('book12');



    if ( val1 === 'ALL')
    {

        $('li').each( function() {
            $(this).removeClass('hidden');
        });

    }
    else 
    {
        $('li').each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf(val2 || val3 || val4 || val5 ||val6 || val7 || val8 || val9 || val10 || val11 || val12 || val13) > 0) {
                console.log('not a match');
            }else{
                $(this).addClass('hidden'); 
            }
        });
    }

});
```

My Problem is that for some reason the program keeps skipping over the if statement when it shouldn't. I have console logged the information and the data is correct. I am thinking it is something wrong with my if statement.

So for example if 'Jolly Rancher' is selected, the list should be filter so only list items with the data-attribute 'Candy' show. Others are hidden.

I need to use the data attribute to filter for other parts of the application so I can't change that. It is probably something simple but would appreciate any help. The jsfiddle is below to demo

Sorry for the strange var names, had to keep some things out.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ovyrq6pj/11/)

Comment: Please do yourself a favour and create a JS object that holds the attributes instead of adding them all as data attribute to the options. With a simple index being the value of the options as key.

Comment: use val1 == 'ALL' instead of val1 === 'ALL'

Comment: I can't see the condition `if 'Jolly Rancher' is selected` do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found 2 issues. The first is with 'undefined'. If any of the 'valx' vars are undefined it will cause the indexOf call to return -1 everytime.

```
val1 = val1 == 'undefined' ? '' : val1;
val2 = val2 == 'undefined' ? '' : val2;
val3 = val3 == 'undefined' ? '' : val3;
val4 = val4 == 'undefined' ? '' : val4;
val5 = val5 == 'undefined' ? '' : val5;
val6 = val6 == 'undefined' ? '' : val6;
```

The other issue was your indexOf check. It should check if the index is >-1 as 0 can be a legit index.

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf(val2 || val3 || val4 || val5 || val6) > -1)
```

EDIT:

As you noted in your comment the above works, but if an element has multiple data values then it'll only show 1 li. To fix this I would change how you store and search for the indexOf a little bit.

Store the `valx` values in an array instead of seperate vars

```
var values = new Array();
values.push(val1 == 'undefined' ? '' : val1);
values.push(val2 == 'undefined' ? '' : val2);
values.push(val3 == 'undefined' ? '' : val3);
values.push(val4 == 'undefined' ? '' : val4);
values.push(val5 == 'undefined' ? '' : val5);
values.push(val6 == 'undefined' ? '' : val6);
```

Then, instead of using the `||` in the indexOf call just search the new array for the `$(this).text()` value:

```
if(values.indexOf($(this).text()) > -1) { console.log('executed');}                
else{ $(this).hide(); }
```

I also added `$('li').show();` to the beginning of the call to reset the list everytime the dropdown is changed.

New JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bh55ux8j/1/

Comment: Ther is actually one piece that still doesn't work. I want ALL the options with the data attribute to be shown. But this goes only one deep. In this example if 'Onion' is selected it has to data values - 'Food' & 'Vegetables'. Both should show but only 'Vegetables' does.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have problem with your `if` statement, use `< 0` instead

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf(val2 || val3 || val4 || val5 ||val6 || val7 || val8 || val9 || val10 || val11 || val12 || val13) < 0) {
    console.log('not a match');
}
else {
    $(this).addClass('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Different approach looping over the whole data object for each element. This approach is far more scale able when adding items to the list of options since it will work regardless of how many data attributes exist and won't require refactoring the conditional code

```
$('#mankList').change(function () {
    // get the whole data object from selected option
    var data = $(this).find(':selected').data();
   // hide all items, start filtering
    $items.hide().filter(function () {
        var isMatch = false,
            txt = $(this).text();
        // loop over data object to check values against text
        for (var key in data) {
            if (data[key] != 'undefined') {
                if (txt.indexOf(data[key]) > -1) {
                    isMatch = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return isMatch;
     // finally ... show matching elements
    }).show();

});
```

This would be much simpler using an array of values in one data attribute

<kbd>[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kzbgnwhv/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

undefined is a string when you set it to undefined in the attribute.

```
"undefined"===undefined  //false
```

If you were to remove the ones that were not defined, it would pick up the ones that are defined.

Other issue is you do not ever show the lis so if you were to change them again, they would remain hidden.